# Download data and update MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am looking for some guidance and hopefully someone can tell me the proper way to implement this scenario. In my app I am going to show a splash screen on startup and immediately start downloading some data from internet. When splash screen is finished, after about three seconds, the mapview should be shown. When the downloading of data is finished, after about one to ten seconds, the mapview should be updated with points of interest relating to the downloaded data. How do I best implement this in Android. Of course I first have an activity for the splash screen and another mapactivity for the mapview. But what do I use to download the data and when it is finished notify the mapactivity to update the mapview? Do I use an asynctask?

Best regards

P

Answer (score 0):

SplashScreen does not need to be a separate Activity since it does not handle user events.

Just put splash screen and mapview inside one activity. Use `FrameLayout` to position splash screen on top of mapview.

Start loading data when Activity starts (onCreate). Use AsyncTask to do network communication in the background while correctly updating view when data arrives.

Create `Handler` and call `postDelayed()` to dismiss splash screen after some time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But say I really would like to have Splash and Map in separate Activities to separate them from each other, would it be possible to start a AsyncTask from SplashActivity and start MapActivity and let MapActivity get feedback from AsyncTask when it is finished.

Comment: It should be possible. I don't know how well this would work. When you start MapActivity you should not show any content (setView(..)) until AsyncTask is finished.